# Why Should We Encoding Data Into Bytes in Post Request

Tags: http, httprequest

to send Post Request we have to convert data into bytes
and then write the data to request body
is it because data move over the internet like binary?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you, see (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx) "Create POST data and convert it to a byte array." why convert data into bytes